# Selenium Webdriver http.client.BadStatusLine: ' ' error?

Tags: firefox, python-3.x, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to get selenium webdriver to work, but even with a simple python script like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.google.com')
driver.quit()
```

I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 14, in <module>
    driver.get('http://www.google.com')
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 207, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 193, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 358, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 389, in _request
    resp = self._conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1171, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 351, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 321, in _read_status
    raise BadStatusLine(line)
http.client.BadStatusLine: ''
```

This has been going on with all the scripts I am trying. Firefox will open and attempt to open the website and then close and then another Firefox instance opens up but is a completely new blank page. I am currently on the latest version of everything. Firefox 31.7.0 ESR (up to date according to Firefox), Selenium 2.46.0, and Python 3.4. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Latest firefox version is 38, have you tried upgrading to any stable release of firefox? Also, have you tried using the same script/code with Chrome?

Comment: I got it to work with firefox version 38, but I was wondering why it would not work with the latest ESR version of firefox. The website says it supports the latest ESR release and the previous ESR release.

Comment: At least it worked, right? I am posting it as an answer.

Comment: Was there any specific reason to use ESR release?

Answer (score 0):

Use Firefox stable releases. Version 38 should work.